# add an element to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, concatenation

I am posting this question after I have done some search over stackoverflow for similar question but not able to find one.

```
const x =  {country: 'Sweden'};
const y =  {{name: 'james',status:'Green'},
   { name: 'Dave', status: 'Yellow'}};
```

Expected Output:

```
const z = {{name: 'james',status:'Green', country: 'Sweden'},
   { name: 'Dave', status: 'Yellow', country: 'Sweden'}};
```

I used forEach loop and tried to .push() or .concat() to an element of the loop, but getting an error "concat is not a function" and "pushis not a function"

```
  y.forEach(function(element) {
    x = x.concat(element); 
    console.log(x);  
  });
```

Comment: There is not a single array declared in your code. Most of it are invalid object declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

constant `y` is wrong according to javascript. First of all, please make it an array like below.

```
const y =  [{name: 'james',status:'Green'},
            { name: 'Dave', status: 'Yellow'}];

const x =  {country: 'Sweden'};
```

Then,

```
y.forEach(function(element) {
   element.country  = x.country; 
   console.log(x);  
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Object.assign()` method:

```
const z = y.map(o => Object.assign(o, x));
```

**Demo:**

```js
const x =  {country: 'Sweden'};
const y =  [
  {name: 'james',status:'Green'},
  {name: 'Dave', status: 'Yellow'}
];

const z = y.map(o => Object.assign(o, x));

console.log(z);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Alternatively you can use spread syntax:

```
const z = y.map(o => ({...o, ...x}));
```

**Demo:**

```js
const x =  {country: 'Sweden'};
const y =  [
  {name: 'james',status:'Green'},
  {name: 'Dave', status: 'Yellow'}
];

const z = y.map(o => ({...o, ...x}));

console.log(z);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**References:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)